# How to auto hide virtual keypad when touch out of editfield?

Tags: java, blackberry, virtual-keyboard

In android, I can do like that where user can click outside of editview to hide the virtual keyboard.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    View v = getCurrentFocus();
    boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    if (v instanceof EditText) {
        View w = getCurrentFocus();
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() || y < w.getTop() || y > w
                        .getBottom())) {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

What about in blackberry? I want to run for `VirtualKeyboard.isSupported()` only.

**Update**

```
public class Custom_EditField extends EditField {
private int width, row, color;
private MainScreen mainscreen;

Custom_EditField(long style, int width, int row, MainScreen mainscreen) {
    super(style);
    this.width = width;
    this.row = row;
    this.mainscreen = mainscreen;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return Font.getDefault().getHeight() * row;
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return width;
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    if (VirtualKeyboard.isSupported())
        mainscreen.getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(
                VirtualKeyboard.SHOW_FORCE);
    invalidate();
    super.onFocus(direction);
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    if (VirtualKeyboard.isSupported())
        mainscreen.getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(
                VirtualKeyboard.HIDE_FORCE);
    invalidate();
    super.onUnfocus();
}

public boolean isFocusable() {
    return true;
}

protected void layout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    super.layout(maxWidth,
            Math.min(maxHeight, Font.getDefault().getHeight() * row));
    super.setExtent(maxWidth,
            Math.min(maxHeight, Font.getDefault().getHeight() * row));
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int rectHeight = getPreferredHeight();
    int rectWidth = getPreferredWidth();
    try {
        color = Color.BLACK;
        graphics.setColor(color);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        super.paint(graphics);
    } finally {
        graphics.setColor(color);
    }
}
}
```

This editfield will hide the keypad if you click on another field but not anypoint.

Comment: so, I just posted an answer about hiding the keyboard.  but, after reading your question again, I realize that the harder problem for you is probably detecting the touch **outside** of the `EditField`.  can you post some of the code that shows how your `EditField` is created?  is it put into a `VerticalFieldManager`?  a custom `Manager` subclass?

Comment: When a touch made outside of the `EditField`, it will lost it's focus. Overriding `onUnfocus` method of the `EditField` may be helpful. But the `EditField` won't lose it's focus if a non-focusable items gets touched.

Comment: Alan, see my update ... I think it will work to override `touchEvent()` in the `Manager` that contains your `Custom_EditField`, instead of overriding `unFocus()`, which doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this utility code for showing, or hiding the keyboard.  This should be valid for OS 4.7 and above.  Let me know if you need to support lower OS versions.

```java
   /** Hides the virtual keyboard, if there is one showing. */
   public static void hideKeyboard() {
      VirtualKeyboard kb = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVirtualKeyboard();
      if (kb != null) {
         kb.setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE);
      }
   }

   /** @return TRUE if the virtual keyboard is hidden, or not supported */
   public static boolean isKeyboardHidden() {
      if (VirtualKeyboard.isSupported()) {
         VirtualKeyboard kb = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVirtualKeyboard();
         if (kb != null) {
            int visibility = kb.getVisibility();
            return ((visibility == VirtualKeyboard.HIDE)
                    || (visibility == VirtualKeyboard.HIDE_FORCE));
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
```

Note that I made these `static` functions.  So, if you put them in a class named `UiUtilities`, then you would call them like:

```java
 if (!UiUtilities.isKeyboardHidden()) {
     UiUtilities.hideKeyboard();
 }
```

As far as **where** to trigger this code, here's what I recommend, **instead of** overriding `onUnfocus()`.  I'm not sure this is the easiest, or most efficient way to solve the problem (so I welcome other answers!), but I think this will work.

I told you a couple answers ago that you normally should **not** override the `touchEvent()` method in your code.  For things like normal buttons, I think that's true.  This might be one example where you need to.  You should have a `Manager` (or `VerticalFielManager`, or similar) that represents the screen that this `EditField` is on.  In that manager, implement the `touchEvent()` method like this:

```java
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;

   protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent event) {
      // We take action when the user completes a click (a.k.a. unclick)
      int eventCode = event.getEvent();
      if ((eventCode == TouchEvent.UNCLICK) || (eventCode == TouchEvent.DOWN)) {
         // Get the touch location, within this Manager
         int x = event.getX(1);
         int y = event.getY(1);

         if ((x >= 0) && (y >= 0) && (x < getWidth()) && (y < getHeight())) {
            int field = getFieldAtLocation(x, y);
            if (field >= 0) {
               // Let event propagate to child field
               return super.touchEvent(event);
            } else {
               if (eventCode == TouchEvent.UNCLICK) {
                  // A completed click anywhere else in this manager should dismiss the keyboard
                  UiUtilities.hideKeyboard();
               } else {
                  // This is just a soft touch (TouchEvent.DOWN), without full click
                  setFocus();
               }
               // Consume the event
               return true;
            }
         }
      }
      // Event wasn't for us, let superclass handle in default manner
      return super.touchEvent(event);
   }
```

Try that.  You might need to change my logic, depending on whether you want to hide the keyboard for a full **click**, versus a simple touch **down** (if you're new to BlackBerry, it might not be clear what the difference between those are).  But, I think this should get you close(r).

Comment: @AlanLai, great.  Thanks for the update.  It looks like your code is doing pretty much what I suggested.  So, it appears that the problem is that if the user clicks outside the `EditField`, but not in another field, that's a click on something that's not **focusable**.  So, focus isn't actually transferred away.  In that case, the containing manager might need to handle it.  Let me take a look at this, and I'll see if I have anything that works like that ...

Comment: @AlanLai, yes it can.  as I said above, it needs to be in the **Manager** class, not in the EditField class.  Manager is where getFieldAtLocation() exists.